# df showing same usage statistics for different mounts

Tags: samba, df

I've run the following df command on my system and get the following output:

```
                                   Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
//loonie/Market Data/EquityBenchmark/EBFS/DEV/DEV_output 5099929736 4861446952 238482784  96% /home/jb5dev/COBRA_OUTPUT
//loonie/Market Data/EquityBenchmark/EBFS/DEV/DEV_input  5099929736 4861446952 238482784  96% /home/jb5dev/COBRA_INPUT
//loonie/Market Data/EquityBenchmark/EBFS/QA/QA_output   5099929736 4861446952 238482784  96% /home/jb5qa/COBRA_OUTPUT
//loonie/Market Data/EquityBenchmark/EBFS/QA/QA_input    5099929736 4861446952 238482784  96% /home/jb5qa/COBRA_INPUT
//loonie/Market Data/EquityBenchmark/EBFS/UAT/UAT_output 5099929736 4861446952 238482784  96% /home/jb5uat/COBRA_OUTPUT
//loonie/Market Data/EquityBenchmark/EBFS/UAT/UAT_input  5099929736 4861446952 238482784  96% /home/jb5uat/COBRA_INPUT
```

Notice that the disk usage statistics are identical for each mount point.  Each mount point is actually a folder that sits on a windows machine.  It seems impossible that each mount point is using and consuming the same amount of space.  I have checked the usage in Windows by doing a right-click and properties on the actual folders.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 8):

> Each mount point is actually a folder that sits on a windows machine.

If those folders are all on the same filesystem, `df` will be reporting that same filesystem's stats for each mount because that's what windows (and I expect any network filesystem) will report.

Comment: @user106563 If this answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted and/or upvote it instead of posting a thank you comment. That is the way thanks are expressed on SE sites.

Comment: @terdon Don't know where to put this, you're here, lucky you: I have to say I don't understand the closure.  I don't see what detail he could have usefully given or  left out, or how his question could be clearer.  What would be the right place to say this?

Comment: If you disagree with the closure of this question you can either vote to reopen ([needs 3k rep](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)) or you can post a question on [meta] about it. A lot of the regular users also hang out in [chat] so you can come and ask there. I did not vote to close this so I can't speak for those who did but the question is not very clear, the `df` command is not shown and one has to infer what is going on (as you did).